# Generic json deserialzation in typescript

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to figure out how to properly implement deserilization making use of typescript generics.

I wrote something like this and at least now I know what type is returned. Is that correct?
And also, is there any way to improve the code?

```
export interface Deserializable<T> {
    deserialize: (data: string) => T;
}

export class User implements Deserializable<User> {
    private _firstName: string = "";
    private _secondName: string = "";

    get firstName(): string {
        return this._firstName;
    }

    set firstName(val: string) {
        this._firstName = val;
    }

    get secondName(): string {
        return this._secondName;
    }

    set secondName(val: string) {
        this._secondName = val;
    }

    deserialize(data: string): User {
        Object.assign(this, JSON.parse(data));
        return this;
    }
}


let userJSONString = '{"firstName": "John", "secondName": "Roberts"}';
let user = new User().deserialize(userJSONString);
console.log(user.firstName);
```

Comment: nope. `Object.assign(this, JSON.parse(data))` is not helping you to guarantee anything. If `data` is junk, it will still ruin your instance object. Usually `JSON.parse(data) as AssumedType` is enough for "kinda" type-safety... and adding extra layers on top of it is not worth it, coz you 'll be just trying to hide the hack.

Comment: You can start with `const retValue = JSON.parse(data) as AssumedType;` as @c69 suggested. But do not stop there, rather continue to scrutinize `retValue` depending how much trust/mistrust you have in sender and what the security requirements are. E.g. use `retValue.hasOwnProperty("name")` or `retValue.hasOwnProperty("age")` then check `parseInt(retValue.age)` to see if it looks like a number and so forth. When JSON.parse() runs there is no Typescript around and no type safety it provides.

Comment: Alright, I got it. Thank you, guys. And what about joi validation then? Seems like it will fit in pretty well in here, right?